# I'm understanding this math about inverse functions

Tags: functions

[image: This is the math]

The problem I have is,

Firstly it mentions,

$y=x+5$....... (i)

Then it mentions,

$y=x-5$.......(ii)

From (i) and (ii) we get,

$x+5=x-5$

$\implies 5=-5$

Could anyone please explain this?

If there's any problem in my question please inform me. Thanks!

Comment: inverses do not mean equality... In fact the only function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ whose inverse is itself is the identity, $f(x) = x$. Instead, being invertible means that for a function $f$ there exists an inverse of $f$ which we will call $g$ such that $f(g(x)) = x$ and $g(f(x)) = x$. A lot of people miss that this relation must hold both ways

Comment: I agree with @Alerra. Indeed it is written $y=x+5$ and (later) $y=x-5$, but these represent different functions and they are not at all equal.

Comment: It is not the same $x,y. f$ is onto doesn't mean $y=x+5$

Comment: @Alerra. Isn't $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(0)=0$ and $f(x) = 1/x$ when $x \neq 0$ its own inverse? And $f(x) = 1-x$?

Comment: @md2perpe Yea, you're right. I realized this after the 5 min period when I could edit my comment. I should have said: Any function for which $f(x) = y$ and $f(y) = x$ is its own inverse. In other words, if it symmetrical about the line $y=x$. My mistake.